# Мета теги для фейсбука(meta property="og:image" )

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

Как мне прописать `meta property="og:image"` для фейсбука?

Картинку к посту я получаю следующим образом:

```
<img src="<?=$post['Post']['image'];?>" alt="<?=$post['Post']['title'];?>" / >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте разметку [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) на свою страницу.

Например:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>Мой красивый тайтл</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Заголовок" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Ссылка" />
<meta property="og:image" content="URL Картинки" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в разметку в секцию `head` мета тег:

```
<head>
...
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$post['Post']['image'];?>" />
</head>
```

Причем адрес картинки должен быть абсолютным!

Comment: а если у меня нет в нужном файле главных тегов как таковых??

Comment: @DaVinchi что вы имеете ввиду под главными? Если нету тегов `head`, то скорее всего они находятся в layout'е

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я сглупил)
Я просто недавно с кейком работаю. 
Попробую - сообщу о результатах.